# Event Handling - React

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, material-ui, dom-events, react-props

I have a `popover` inside which there are `Colors` components with different colors. Also there is a icon  `DoneIcon` which (for time being) is placed inside the `Colors` component. What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. After hovering when I select a color(with no icon inside), `DoneIcon` should be placed inside it. To generalize when a color is selected it should have `DoneIcon` and the icon should disappear from the previously selected color.
2. When the color is selected the background color of (its parent) `div` with `class="box"` should change to the selected color. I know this can be achieved with event handling by having functions for each color(out of 12 colors) which will be executed `onClick`, but how can I have only one function which will detect the color from `props.color` when `onClick` event executes and apply the color to `box`.

Here is the link for [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-palette-9i350?file=/src/Colors.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a selected prop to your Colors component

```
function Colors(props) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.setColor(props.color)}
      className="colors"
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}
    >
      {props.selected && <DoneIcon fontSize="small" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your parent:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("");
...

<Colors selected={color === "red"} setColor={setColor} color="red" />
```

Note: you'll probably want to refactor this solution, but something like this should work.

### Thoughts on refactoring

Map over a list of colors

```
const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState('')

['red', 'blue', 'green'].map(color => {
  <div onClick={() => setSelectedColor(color)} className="colors" style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
    {selectedColor === color && <DoneIcon fontSize="small" />}
  </div>
}
```

Working: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-palette-forked-xl0hx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Refactored to use Colors component: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-palette-forked-lmibm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I used your code but its not working. The only change happened is the last `Colors` component placed in parent gets checked by default. If this is not what should happen according to you can you please make changes to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-palette-9i350?file=/src/Colors.jsx) and share the link?

Comment: @Rohit Yep. I added two links to the answer. The first one is the first pass (before refactor). The second one uses your Colors component.

Comment: @ JWilk You saved my day!! After refactoring the code is really clean!

Comment: One thing I didn't understand, why did you passed `classes` while declaring `const HoverPopoverPopupState` ?

Comment: Glad to help! It looks like that may have been some dead code from your original code. I see it in your codesandbox.